# Create common method for volley Request and response

Tags: android, object, casting

I use Volley in my application for request and response . the problem is i should call following line to get request through volley and the difference between these line is just the type of object witch `jsonArray` should cast to(like NewsItem) second problem is showing object's value in the xml layout after get response. is there any way to summarize these lines in one method and call this method fore different object types?

```
 private void GetOnlineNewsContent() {
    CacheRequest cacheRequest = new CacheRequest(ContentActivity.this,Request.Method.POST,
            service_address,
            new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    try {

                        final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);


                        newsItem = NewsItem.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0), term_id);
                        ShowContent(newsItem);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should look at and learn `Generics` in Java.

You would need to make this new method to receive generic type, and then perform the operation on particular type of the class.

For that, your `newItem` and other 3 classes should come from common base class.

Basic tutorial on generics can be found here,
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: thanks , and how to tell my activity that my response is available and show value in xml?

Comment: If you are using just one activity then pass that `Activity` context in the method itself, or if you're using multiple activities then you probably want to create some kind of interface with a method, and then all activities should implement that interface.

Comment: @serenei Please accept the answer if it answers your question satisfactorily

Comment: could you please explain more ? or give me an example code?

Comment: It would be difficult to show an example code because each example code may be different depending on type of application. Please look for "interface design pattern" for java language. You may learn what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @serenei Also, it's a different question than this, so based on Stackoverflow policy, please post a new question regarding how to implement interface or something if you still can't figure it out.